# Trigger an action when an app is pushed to cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I know that cloud foundry events can be pulled with cf api request. But can I do anything to make cf perform some operation immediately when an app is pushed to it (or is stopped, or any other event)? For example, once I've pushed the app to cf I want cf to automatically send a message. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164909/cloud-foundry-app-status-or-health-notification

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to make the platform do this for you, not with out-of-the-box features, but you might consider using CI/CD pipelines to deploy your apps. In that case, you can simply have the pipeline send a message once the app has deployed successfully.

If you can't/don't want to do that, you'd need to have something that polls the [events api](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/6.3.0/events/list_all_events.html). There is no "push" event, so you'd need to look for an even that is triggered when a push occurs, like `audit.app.create` and `audit.app.update`. When you find one, you could then kick off some action, like sending a message.

Just be careful with how often you're polling this API as it will add load onto your Cloud Controllers.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the reason I asked this question was that I wanted to find another way of doing it without having to poll the api:)

Comment: Figured as much, it's unfortunately not possible though.